# uniqueness of positive operator

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $A,B$ be commuting positive operators on a Hilbert space such that $\langle(A-B)(A+B)x,x\rangle=0$ for all $x$ in the Hilbert space. Prove that $A=B$.

My attempt: The above implies that $A=B$ on the image of $A+B$, hence on the closure on the image. So I have to show $A=B$ on the kernel of $A+B$. How to proceed?

Comment: If $\langle(A-B)(A+B)x,x\rangle=0\forall x\in H$, then
$$(A-B)(A+B)x=0$$
Thus,
$$(A-B)(A+B)=0$$

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar: you seem to be assuming that if the product of two operators is zero, then one of them is zero. This is not usually true.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I edited my comment.

Comment: Since the operators commute $(A-B)(A+B)=A^2-B^2$. So, $A^2=B^2$. Since the operators are positive they have a unique positive square root.

Answer (score 4):

I think I have answered this for you before, but I'll explain it again in more detail. The proof hinges on the following lemma, whose proof is given at the end. Perhaps you'll accept this answer.

> **Lemma** Let $X$ be a complex Hilbert space and let $T\in\mathcal{L}(X)$ satisfy $(Tx,x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in X$. Then $(Tx,x)=0$ iff $Tx=0$. That is, $\mathcal{N}(T)=\{ x : (Tx,x)=0 \}$.

Let $X$ be a complex Hilbert space, and let $A, B \in \mathcal{L}(X)$ satisfy $(Ax,x) \ge 0$ and $(Bx,x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in X$. Clearly $((A+B)x,x) \ge 0$ and $((A+B)x,x) = 0$ iff $(Ax,x)=0=(Bx,x)$. Therefore, the above lemma proves that $\mathcal{N}(A+B)=\mathcal{N}(A)\cap\mathcal{N}(B)$.

If $X$ is a complex Hilbert space and $A, B \in \mathcal{L}(X)$ are commuting positive operators on $X$ such that $A^{2}=B^{2}$, then
$$
                     (A-B)(A+B)=0.
$$
Consequently $A-B=0$ on $\mathcal{R}(A+B)^{c}$ ('c' denotes closure.) But $A-B=0$ also holds on the orthogonal complement
$$
     \mathcal{R}(A+B)^{\perp}=\mathcal{N}(A+B)=\mathcal{N}(A)\cap\mathcal{N}(B).    
$$
Thus $A=B$ because $A-B=0$ on
$$
                X = \mathcal{R}(A+B)^{c}\oplus \mathcal{N}(A+B).
$$

**To prove the lemma** Let $T \ge 0$ on the complex Hilbert space $X$. For each $\epsilon > 0$, $(x,y)_{\epsilon}=((T+\epsilon I)x,y)$ is an inner product on $X$ because $T+\epsilon I$ is positive definite. By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$
        |(x,y)_{\epsilon}|^{2} \le (x,x)_{\epsilon}(y,y)_{\epsilon}.
$$
Letting $\epsilon$ tend to $0$ gives
$$
                  |(Tx,y)|^{2} \le (Tx,x)(Ty,y),\;\;\; x,y \in X.
$$
If $(Tx,x)=0$ for some $x$, then $(Tx,y)=0$ for all $y$, which implies $Tx=0$.

**NOTE:** You can find a positive square root $P$ of $A^{\star}A$ that commutes with every $B\in \mathcal{L}(X)$ that commutes with $A^{\star}A$. And you can do this without the functional calculus, using only sequences of polynomials in $A^{\star}A$. In fact, such a square root can be used to supply an alternative proof of the spectral theorem. The polar decomposition does not require the full power the spectral theorem.

Answer (score 2):

As $A$ and $B$ commute, you have $\langle (A^2-B^2)x,x\rangle=0$ for all $x$, so $A^2=B^2$. Now you can use that both $A,B$ are positive, so $A$ is the unique positive square root of $A^2$, and likewise with $B$. So $A=B$.

I don't immediately see how to prove that $A=B$ in the kernel of $A+B$ other than doing what I did above, which shows $A=B$ everywhere.

Comment: I'm sorry @Martin Argerami but my aim in doing this is showing that the positive square root is unique! which perhaps illustrates the importance of giving context. Here's what I've thought: Let $x$ be in the kernel of $A+B$. then $0=\langle(A+B)x,x\rangle=\langle{Ax,x}\rangle+\langle{Bx,x}\rangle$ Since $A,B$ are positive we get $\langle{Ax,x}\rangle$=$\langle{Bx,x}\rangle=0$ from which we can conclude. What do you think. Seems very tortuous.

Comment: Yes, you are right: that works. But if you want to show the uniqueness of the square root, why would you assume that $AB=BA$?

Comment: it's not assumed, it follows from the functional calculus.

Comment: If you are using functional calculus, then why the awkward proof? You take $f(t)=t^{1/2}$, and you can assume that $A=f(A^2)$. Then $$ B=f(B^2)=f(A^2)=A.$$

Comment: I agree $f(A^2)$ is a square root. But to prove it is unique you have to assume there is a $B$ with $B^2=A^2$. You can't assume $B=f(A^2)$

Comment: I didn't assume that $B=f(A^2)$. I assumed that $B^2=A^2$; this guarantees that $f(B^2)=f(A^2)$. And you also have $B=f(B^2)$ by functional calculus. The point is that since $t=f(t^2)$ for $t\geq0$, the same happens for any positive operator.

Comment: I may well be wrong here but I believe you are tacitly assuming $B$ can be represented as $g(B^2)$ for some function $g$. The functional calculus is not surjective however.

Comment: It is not "some function" and it has nothing to do with surjectivity. The function $f:t\mapsto \sqrt t$ maps, for $t> 0$, $t^2$ to $t$. That is, $f(t^2)=t$ for $t> 0$. When applied to the positive operator $B$, this last equality gives $f(B^2)=B$.

Comment: ok I guess the bit I'm not getting is $f(B^2)=B$. It just looks like you're assuming what is to be proved.

Comment: It is not assuming what is to be proved. It's just the way functional calculus works. If $f(t)=2t^2+2$, then $f(b)=2B^2+2$. If $f(g(t))=t$, then $f(g(B))=B$. In this case, $g(t)=t^2$, $f(t)=\sqrt t$. For $t\geq0$, $f(g(t))=t$, so for positive $B$, $f(g(B))=B$, i.e. $f(B^2)=B$.

Comment: I'm a determined fellow, I hope you're a patient one.If $f(t)=2t^2+2$ then $f(T)=(\int{\lambda}^2+1\,dE)=T^2+1$. I can see that fine because the integral is multiplicative and linear (basically the functional calculus). But the square root is not a polynomial so we can't just use the multiplicativity and linearity of the integral. So I can't see how you are applying $f$ to the integral.

Comment: :D You use $f(T)=\int f(\lambda)\,dE$ to define $f(T)$ for any Borel function $f$. So if $f(t)=\sqrt t$, then $$ f(B^2)=\int f(\lambda^2)\,dE=\int\lambda\,dE=B,$$ where we can use $f(\lambda^2)=\lambda$ from the fact that $\sigma(B)\subset[0,\infty)$.

Comment: All the time the problem was you know a bit of functional calculus I do not. That is, $(f{\circ}g)(T)=f(g(T))$. Is there a nice proof of this-Rudin does not cover it for some reason

Comment: It can be deduced from facts from the theory; but as I don't know which ones you have available, here is another way: Prove it first in the case where $f(t)=t^m$, $g(t)=t^n$, and extend to polynomials. Then use that continuous functions over a compact set are uniform limits of polynomials.